# How to get the 2D slice in a 3D array in which a given number occurs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array, which I want to mask by a given value. The value only occurs in one 2D slice of that 3D array along the z direction (axis 0) of that array, so all other slices along the z direction will be False.

**How can i extract only the 2d array in which the number occurs, and also the position in the z dimension of the 2d slice in which it occurs?**

So lets say i have a small 3D array:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros((3,3,3))
array[2] = np.array([[2,2,0],[2,2,0],[2,2,0]])
print(array==2)
```

So masking the 3d array with value 2, would give me the whole 3d array, but i only need the 2d slice where it occurs, in that case it would be the third slice in the 3d array.

**Desired Output:**

```
 [[ True  True False]
  [ True  True False]
  [ True  True False]]

slice: 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you specifically type the desired output?

Comment: For general case, the `True` might occur in more than 2 dimension.

Comment: What are the input(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know, that the condition is only fulfilled along the axis you call z direction, you can use a combination of [`numpy.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html). You can use `(array==2)` to get a boolean array to find out where condition is met and then use `np.any` to find the correct slice. You can then find the slice index using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and then extract that index:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros((3,3,3))
array[2] = np.array([[2,2,0],[2,2,0],[2,2,0]])
valueToFind = 2
conditionMet = (array==valueToFind)
zIndex = np.where(conditionMet.any(axis=(1, 2)))[0][0]
print(conditionMet[zIndex])
print("slice: {}".format(zIndex))
```

Alternatively, you can use [`np.compress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html) to extract the slice.

```
np.compress(conditionMet.any(axis=(1, 2)), conditionMet, axis=0)[0]
```

Note, however, that this will not give you the z Index. So if you need that, you will need to use `np.where` anyway.

Comment: Ok nice, but is it possible to get the boolean array directly? :)

Comment: I know , maybe I should wrote another question, but know you understand what its about and i think it should be an easy command, but how would I now replace all of the 3 slices in that 3d array with the boolean 2d slice, which I extracted?, so that all of the 3 2d slices are the same

Comment: @Liwellyen Do you really want to replace it with the boolean values or do you want to repeat the original slice? For the latter just do: `array[:]=array[zIndex]`. For the former: would you also want to change the `dtype` of the array to bool then?